# In cocos2dx 3.2, Whatever functionality, that I put inside Update(float dt) is making app to crash

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Example :

```
 `void HelloWorld::Update(float dt)
 {
       auto action = MoveBy::create(dt,Vec2(2,this->getPositionY()));
      _ball->runAction(action);

 }`
```

This doesn't work. But when I put the same piece of code withing init() method, it works. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stop update after you run your animation on Ball inside update method using 
**this->unscheduleUpdate();** . Update is called per frame, so in just 6 frames you will call 6 times this same action. It might be a issue.

Comment: Tried doing what you mentioned. Still the game crashes.

Comment: ok I found it, _Ball is a defined as auto in your init() function. Move its deceleration to your .h file and it should run. Actually _ball  instance is local and valid in init() only.

Comment: Not sure which .h file should contain instance of type CBall. Please elaborate. I tried doing something similar. Din't work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was busy for last few days. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: change you HelloWroldScene.h file to something like This 
#include "CBall.h"
USING_NS_CC;
class CBall;
and after public: declaration write
CBall _ball;

in your HelloWorldScene.cpp file remove #include 'CBall.cpp"
and change line 58 to:- _ball = CBall::createWithFileName(FileName);

Comment: Thank you for reply and very sorry for the fact that I forgot to tell that the problem is solved. I added one variable in my main cpp file i.e HelloWorld.cpp named global_ball, before the ball gets auto-collected, I assign that to this global_ball value. Although retain() method on auto object didn't work for me. Everythin is working fine now. Thanks LazyGamer.